# Nature of particle spectra at ALICE

Tags: particle-physics, large-hadron-collider, elementary-particles

I have a question regarding the nature of the particle spectrum at [ALICE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALICE:_A_Large_Ion_Collider_Experiment) as a function of momentum. The spectra in question [can be seen here](http://cerncourier.com/cws/article/cern/48325).

My question is, why is it that the particle spectrum in the low momentum range is rising, then reaching a maximum and then beginning to decrease again. From what I have understood it has something to do with the Fermi theory of beta decay. It would be awesome it anyone knew and you give me a hint on it.

Comment: Is it just me or did they really go with this illegible font?

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you looked at the papers referenced? The hydrodynamic model is not something I am familiar with, but it may explain some or all of the structure seen here in relatively simple terms. Of course the plot is of non-trivial complexity: its a double differential cross-section as a function of transverse momentum at for maximally central events. Presumably each of those facts (double differential; depending on transverse momentum; maximally central events) are important.

Comment: I have tried to look at hydrodynamic model, but can't find anything about it. I was thinking that it may be because of the collision, that High momentum particles are unlikely and the low momentum particles are Also unlikely because of the forces and the limited energy avaliable. But i have no Clue why

Comment: High-A collision physics is far enough outside my specialization that I hesitate to say *anything*. I *think* that maximum centrality implies roughly equal Borjken-x for the active partons, but that is as far as my knowledge goes.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I would think that the rise & fall just be an effect of the cross section increasing (causing the rise) then the particle population decreasing (causing the decline).

Comment: @KyleKanos In a lot of contexts, that's what I'd guess, too. But I just don't trust my instincts when it comes to heavy ion collisions.

Comment: Well that make some sense. But then, why would the cross-section increase cause the rise in graph. if we imaging that more lightweight particles are produced than heavy particles, due to the limited energy available. Then how would the cross-section evolve in the graph (the rise). I see that it increased in the beginning and the begin falling later.

Comment: The difference between bosons (pions etc) and fermions (protons) etc is the standard Bose enhancement vs Pauli blocking (no relation to Fermi theory of beta decay). Also note that there is a trivial phase space effect $d^2p_T=p_Tdp_T$.

Comment: This look a lot like a thermal production + an average radial flow, which would create a peak in the low $p_T$ region of the spectra. I worked on hydro simulations for heavy ion, this kind of behaviour happened with the combination that I said above, I can detail a bit more if you wish.

Comment: @MortenSode: One way to think of it is with the analogy of the [Gamow peak](http://nu.phys.laurentian.ca/~fleurot/fusionrate/) (you'll have to scroll down a little). The distribution function drops off at a higher energies while the tunneling probability increases at the higher energies. The two functions together give the combined peak, which is similar (at least in concept) to the case here.

Comment: @KyleKanos I have read about Gamow peak and i think it could be used here. Thank you. And HydroGuy could detail it a bit more.